# React component not rendering on DOM

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, webpack

I'm walking through a react tutorial at http://andrewhfarmer.com/build-your-own-starter/#0-intro and the `Counter` component won't show up on the page. The html comes out like this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="/bundle.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="mount"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js

```
console.log('Hello World!');
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Counter from './Counter';


ReactDOM.render(
    React.createElement(Counter),
    document.getElementById('mount')
);
```

Counter.js

```
import React from 'react';


class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            count: 0,
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
                }}
            >
                Count: {this.state.count}
            </button>
        );
    }
}

export default Counter;
```

webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');

var config = {
  context: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
  entry: [
    './main.js',
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'www'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loaders: ['babel-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
  resolveLoader: {
    root: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    ],
  },
  resolve: {
    root: [
      path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules'),
    ],
  },
};
module.exports = config;
```

We run server:

```
cchilders@cchilders-Latitude-E7240:~/CodeTutorials/build-react-starter$ node server.js 
in the component
in the tester
in the component
in the tester
Example app listening at http://:::3000
Hash: d51a7c75081bea020fb1
Version: webpack 1.14.0
Time: 1297ms
    Asset    Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
bundle.js  744 kB       0  [emitted]  main
chunk    {0} bundle.js (main) 707 kB [rendered]
    [0] multi main 28 bytes {0} [built]
 [179] ./src/Counter.js 2.63 kB {0} [built]
webpack: bundle is now VALID.
```

Refreshing page shows nothing in terminal, but developer tools console shows the `Hello World!` on each refresh

It seems template isn't being rendered, but the last time my friend did the tutorial it worked as is (the `public` aspect in the middleware might have served it)

Why is this server not serving files from `/`?

The code is at https://bitbucket.org/servandoavila1/codetutorials

Thank you

Comment: nothing in the console?

Comment: I added console above, it does the prints you'd expect. The Chrome console prints the `Hello world!` when you refresh page

Answer (score 1):

There is no need for you to use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {`.

```js
class Counter extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            count: 0,
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <button
                onClick={() => {
                    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
                }}
            >
                Count: {this.state.count}
            </button>
        );
    }
}


    ReactDOM.render(
        React.createElement(Counter),
        document.getElementById('mount')
    );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="mount"></div>
```

Comment: do you know why that breaks it?

Comment: I did it your way and surprisingly doesn't work. Using google chrome, have hard refreshed. No errors on server or frontend

Comment: It doesnt make any difference but could you try <Counter/> instead of React.createElement

Answer (score 0):

When did you last run `npm run compile`?

I just did the tutorial myself and ran into the same issue that you did. I was able to resolve it by running `npm run compile` again after adding the React stuff.

It seems that the tutorial may be missing a step, since bundle.js needs to be compiled again after React is added.

Answer (score 0):

try to set the publicPath on your webpack config

```
var config = {
  ...
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'www'),
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js',
  },
  ...
}
```

And make sure you have `['es2015', 'react']` presets on your `.babelrc`

Tips: on main.js you can do like this

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <Counter />,
    document.getElementById('mount')
);
```

Answer (score 0):

use JSX loader as below in your loader.config.js file :

```
loaders: [
     {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',

        query: {
           presets: ['es2015', 'react']
        }
     }
  ]
```